# How to set border to 0 in this table

Tags: html, css

[image]

In the image above First Name and Textfield are not aligned from the left. I don't know whether its border or padding. But the image inside  is conditionally visible. How to get rid of it just by html and css.

```
<div id=first_name>
    First Name<br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" id="form_first_name_err_img" style='display: none' /></td>
            <td><input align="middle" id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg" style='display: none'>This cannot be left blank.</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><!-- eof first_name -->
```

Comment: You mean margin, not border right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
         <img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" 
                    id="form_first_name_err_img" style='display: none' />
     </td>
     <td>
         <input align="middle" id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" 
                            type="text" name="first_name" />
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="2">
          <span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg"
              style='display: none'>This cannot be left blank.
          </span>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

try this

Comment: `callpadding` and `cellspacing` attributes of `table` element are not supported by HTML5

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that even though you have the image hidden, there is still a `<td>` element, I made a few changes to the code, I put the First Name into a `<td>` to align with your input. Also wrapped it in a label. I removed the td the image was in, you could either put it in the same cell as the input, or dynamically add it with javascript and take it out completely (this would be my approach).

```
<div id=first_name>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
   <label for='form_first_name'>First Name:</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>

  <td><img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image"     id="form_first_name_err_img" style='display: none;' /><input align="middle"     id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="first_name" />
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg"     style='display: none'>This cannot be left blank.</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div><!-- eof first_name -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Set border to 0 in table tag as shown below

```
<table  border="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

While putting the archaic: `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` would still produce good enough results in most (backward compatible) browsers, attributes `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` are not supported in HTML5 and shouldn't be used.

Rather put something like this in your stylesheet:

```
#first_name table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
#first_name td {
    padding: 0;
}
#first_name input { 
    margin: 0;
}
```

Of course, you can add classes to your elements and update the stylesheet accordingly.

TIP: For future similar problems, try using dev tools in your browser of choice and investigate what default style is being applied to the elements, so you can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="first_name">First Name</div>
<table class="tables" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" id="form_first_name_err_img" style='display: none' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input align="middle" id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="first_name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg" style='display: none'>This cannot be left blank.</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2XX5/4/)

## **OR**

**HTML**

```
<div id="first_name">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <input align="middle" id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="first_name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" id="form_first_name_err_img" style='display: none' />
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg" style='display: none'>This cannot be left blank. </span>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2XX5/11/)